# validate the date based on its format in python

Tags: python, python-3.6

In Python, I want to validate the date based on its format.
I want to get both `/` and `-`.
For example - `22/04/2002` and `22-04-2002`

```
if billDate == datetime.strptime(str(billDate, '%d/%m/%Y')).date():
    billDate = datetime.strptime(billDate, '%d/%m/%Y')
elif billDate == datetime.strptime(str(billDate, '%d-%m-%Y')).date():
    billDate = datetime.strptime(billDate, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

In this, I am trying to get the date first in `/` format and then the other format that is with `-`.
Now does string take `/` and `-` the way I wrote?

Comment: Can't you just do `billDate.replace("/", "-)` to get only `-` ?

Comment: Your code is not "getting the date format" you're parsing a string into a date with a non-performant way

Comment: Nope, the way I show you in my answer, don't check in which format to parse. Modify the input to get format you want, in one line you're done

Comment: I dont want to replace anything. Can you use If and elif condition to prove that?

Comment: The replacement is not done like in your HTML file or wherever, you won't even see it, the replacement take only place in the line I show as answer, this allows to parse the date in one short WHATEVER the input date is, with slash or hyphen

Comment: You can have 2 if to find whether you have a - or a /, but to check the whole format and find the full demiter you'll need a **4** if/else, so just use replace. If you're now ok whith that, I'll stop here, not here to fight and impose my vision ;)

Answer (score 1):

At the end, what you care is getting a date instance, no matter the way you parse it, so replace the slash by a hiphen

```
billDate = datetime.strptime(billDate.replace("/", "-"), '%d-%m-%Y')
# date only
billDate = datetime.strptime(billDate.replace("/", "-"), '%d-%m-%Y').date()
```

---

And you'll get through this

```
billDate = "12/12-2020"
billDate = datetime.strptime(billDate.replace("/", "-"), '%d-%m-%Y')
print(billDate) # 2020-12-12 00:00:00
```

Comment: I dont want to print the value. I just need to use IF else. If date format in "/" then BILLDATE = ?  and if date format in "-"  then BILLDATE = ?

Comment: @AchalSajeev what is the goal of your code ? You check if the parsing to date is equal to the initial thing what's the purpose ?

Comment: I have an HTML file, from which I want to parse the date. In some files it is in "/" format and in some its in "-"format, but either way the date is correctly formatted. I want to get the date in both format and store that in billdate variable. If date in %d / %m / %Y format billdate = / format and vice versa.

Comment: @AchalSajeev so at the end you just want the parsed date ? that's what my code does, you 'replace' the char oly for the method purpose

Answer (score 0):

You could use the dateutil library;

`from dateutil import parser
parser.parse(billDate)`